# Errorcode 800a0bb9

Tags: asp-classic

I'm reviving an old ASP Classic app for a client. The database is up and running, but it seems the app is having trouble connecting to it.

There is no readme or database configuration file. I searched the codebase for any Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") statements but couldn't find any.
I also searched for some kind of initialization of the cnnDB variable which seems to hold the ADODB connection, but to no avail.

Adovbs.inc is included in Default.asp line 10:

```
 10 <!--#include file="includes/adovbs.inc" --> 
 11 <!--#include file="includes/pageinit.asp" -->
```

Log file:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2015-09-03 14:55:57
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2015-09-03 14:55:57 ::1 GET / |41|800a0bb9|Arguments_are_of_the_wrong_type__are_out_of_acceptable_range__or_are_in_conflict_with_one_another. 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 500 0 0 46
```

Errorcode 800a0bb9 at line 41 in Default.asp

Default.asp:

```
38 Dim rsAccount_configuration,strSQLaccount_configuration
39 Set rsAccount_configuration = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
40 strSQLaccount_configuration="select * from account_configuration where username='" & session("username") & "'"
41 rsAccount_configuration.Open strSQLaccount_configuration, cnnDB, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

Comment: What does this have to do with vba(OOP language for Office and other applications)?

Comment: The only content that's included/processed in Classic ASP that isn't listed as an include in the targeted URL is global.asa. It'd be odd to find objects created there, but you might have a look. At the very minimum, most define their connection string in global.asa to protect the connection parameters from casual observation, and to make them available to all ASP pages.

Comment: You must debug this. Add `Response.Write(TypeOf(cnnDB))` before the line with error and see what you get. If you get Empty, it means you don't have any connection defined, i.e. you missed a file to include.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a bunch guys. The solution was to add the following to pageinit.asp

```
set cnnDB=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnnDB.Open "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=myserver;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=mydb"
```

@Shadow Wizard, cnnDB was indeed Empty